# XCode, Authentication and NSUserDefaults

Tags: php, mysql, xcode, authentication

I am developing an App that will interface with a web server (PHP with MySQL back end) using web views. I have the application working with static URL's as tests, but now I need to adjust for actual user interaction.

I have been looking for solutions to HTTP authentication but believe the phrase to be incorrect as most of the search results I get are all related to "REST" requests. I will be using a URL (PHP / MySQL) to validate authentication and do not believe that qualifies as REST based on my experience.

I do not have SSL as of yet on this server so I am not sure what options are available via Cocoa.

Questions I have:

1. Is there a way to create a View that loads if the account ID isn't already stored locally?
2. If so, can i code the app to supersede the storyboard I have created if authentication is needed?
3. If step 1 and 2 work, how can I interface with my web server to authenticate? ( preferred method is to submit user email and the MD5 of the password as that is what is currently stored in the database)

Ideally i would love to just submit a url like "login.php?login=me@blah.com&password=(md5hash)" and have the provided response either give me "auth=true&accountID=5" or "auth=false" ... then use the iPhone app to either report an auth error to the user or save the account id to NSUserDefaults for future use (to bypass auth later) and load the normal storyboard already in place.

Any recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Silver Tiger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are pretty close with your thinking. I use a very similar approach to my user login process.

I currently salt and hash the email and password into 1 40 char token. If the login returns successful, I save the token to NSUserDefaults. I use this token for all other web requests going forward until the user logs out, at which time I delete the user defaults.

Here are a few snippets I use for the same process:

```
// see if a login already exists
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
self.token = [defaults stringForKey:@"token"];

// if the token is nil/blank, launch login view
if(self.token == nil || [self.token isEqualToString:@""]) {
    [self loadStartView];
    return;
}

// build the request to update status
[[NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage] setCookieAcceptPolicy:NSHTTPCookieAcceptPolicyNever];
NSString *stringData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<your api string here"];
NSString *requestData = stringData;
NSData *myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestData UTF8String] length: [requestData length]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString  stringWithFormat:@"<your url request here>"]]];
[request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
NSData *jsonData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: nil];
NSString *json = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];
NSDictionary *payloadData = [json JSONValue];

[request release];

if([[payloadData objectForKey:@"success"] boolValue]) { // this is designed around my api, but you get the idea
    //NSLog(@"updateStatus: %@", payloadData);
    // updates the api version for every call
    [defaults setObject:self.token forKey:@"token"];
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I will try to integrate these snippets into my AppDeletage and see how it goes. I will reply to let you know.

Comment: i supposed i need to inquire a bit more .. i get he ideas but don't have the function to override the base launch (tabbed application) and instead launch my auth UIview with code, and once i get auth, can i then proceed to launch the tabbed app as built in the storyboard?

Comment: Notable as the first complaint the app gives me is that there is no method for "JSONValue" ... is this another import I will need to include?

Comment: I have my PHP auth script set to respond with basic JSON as either { "success": "1", AccountID: "account ID", } - OR - { "success": "0", error: "Detailed message here", } .... These should work fine once I get the JSONValue" issue figured out.

Comment: I had to download and include the json library to get that functino to work, and changed ym code to the new version listed in my request above .. not quite what I wanted, but it works ok if my json response from my php url is ["1","4",""] (success, accountid, error)

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have enough space to comment in the notes. Here's the final code. THough not what i wanted it gets the job done:

In order to get JSONValue to work i had to download and include in my project the json frameowrk as seen here:

https://github.com/stig/json-framework

Once I had that in place I was getting an incomplete error from the JSONValue function. my original URL request to my PHP page request was providing the JSON response as follows:

{ 
"success": "0",
"AccountID: "4",
"error": ""
}

For some reason the JSONValue function did not like this output and I had to change it to a more basic less preferred version as follows:

["0","4",""]

Once I had this working the final copy of the code is as follows:

In my main view that loads on app launch I added the following to determine if there was an existing account ID and launch the "Login" view if it was not present:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *accountID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"AccountID"];
    if (![accountID length]) {
        UIViewController *login = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Login"];
        [self presentModalViewController:login animated:YES];
    }
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

The login is nothing more than 2 text fields and a button for authentication.
This is the function I added to the button, and it works currently:

```
-(IBAction)authenticate:(id)sender{
    // This will be the validation code
    // First we'll grab the field values
    NSString *currentEmail = emailField.text;
    NSString *currentPassword = passField.text;
    // Now we will grab the user default settings (saved preferences)
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    // build the request to update status
    NSString *myURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.myurl.com/auth.php?e=%@&p=%@",currentEmail,currentPassword];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]; [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURL]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSArray *responseArray = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSString *success = [responseArray objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *AccountID = [responseArray objectAtIndex:1];
    NSString *error = [responseArray objectAtIndex:2];
    if([success boolValue]) {
        NSLog(@"User is Authenticated");
        UIAlertView *auth1 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"T-of-U" message:@"Successfully Authenticated" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [auth1 show];
        [defaults setObject:AccountID forKey:@"AccountID"];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        NSString *authMessage = error;
        UIAlertView *auth2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Authentication Failed:" message:authMessage delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [auth2 show];
    }
}
```

I would have preferred a key value pair NSDictionary, but every time I sent the json response with key value pairs, the JSONValue failed so I ended up just making it a simple json response and reference objects in array locations to get my variables.

if there is a way to get key value pairs into a dictionary that would be great, though I may not be forming my json response properly (PHP has the json_encode($data) method that creates the json as expected, but the Objective C function won't parse it).

Comment: If you are using the json framework that you have listed, assuming your data is returned in key value pairs, you should be able to cast it into a dictionary as I showed in my answer above. The only way it wouldn't would be that your json string isn't formatted that way.

Comment: yes. I will have to keep trying to interpret how I need to build the reply with key value pairs. my understanding was that a format of {["success":"0","AccountID":"4","error":""]} would work but I tried multiple ways and the JSONView never did work until I simplified to just an array of values ["1","4",""].  I am still working on it as it will benefit me in the future if I can interpret full sets of data for table views etc.  presumably with a huge post. Is it possible my <API string> was incorrect? i presumed it would be my php data elements like: "?blah=blah&blah2=blah2" etc?

Comment: Test your json strings at jsonlint.com You should be able to get them figured out.

Comment: What about security issue? You are sending login and password via GET request?