# Skip log in page by checking NSUserDefaults

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uistoryboard

I am trying to skip over the log in view for my app if a specific `NSUserDefault` is set. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8758992/xcode-authentication-and-nsuserdefaults) but I am still having issue outlined below:

I added a new view to my storyboard and set it to be the view loaded at start. I also set up a segue to fire if a specific `NSUserDefault` was not set.

I am get the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <QMALogInViewController: 0x8838cf0> on <DefaultLoginCheckViewController: 0x7557400> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

View loaded at start:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *accountID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"CurrentUserId"];
    if (![accountID length]) {
        NSLog(@"I should be heading to the log in form");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"notloggedin" sender:self];
    } else{
        NSLog(@"Heading over to CRNA menu");
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"crnaloggedin" sender:self];

    }

    NSLog(@"I should be heading to the log in form");

    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Comment: At first you should now that you should call `[super viewDidLoad]` before you do any additional setup like mentioned in comment in your code. This may cause some problems when subclassing this controller.

Comment: Do you override `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` method? If yes please show it to us.

Comment: Maybe when `[super viewDidLoad]` will be called then this view will be in hierarchy and all start work. Try it. Move `[super viewDidLoad]` to first line of this method. Move rest of your code below.